# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Where is the error? Used Django App with Pipeline

Tags: python, django, postman, pipeline

> ````
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable if
> request['user_type']=='driver' and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id =
> user.id): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable ```
> ````

```py
def create_user_by_type(backend , user , request, response , *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        avatar = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' % response['id']
    if request['user_type'] == 'driver' and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id = user.id):
        Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id,avatar=avatar)
    elif not Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar=avatar)
```

The error is most likely in request `['user_type'] == 'driver'` as it works if I remove this from the code.

I am sending the request from POSTMAN

[image]

I check by parameter `user_type`

Used Pipeline from https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html

If everything is correct, where can there be a mistake?

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update `create_user_by_type`:

```
def create_user_by_type(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    request = backend.strategy.request_data()

    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        avatar = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' % response['id']
    if request['user_type'] == 'driver' and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id = user.id):
        Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id,avatar=avatar)
    elif not Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar=avatar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lie in the object stored in variable `request`.

You get the value for `request` in a function which should return a complex object, which is subscriptable and has a field called `'user type'`. Obviously, it did not return this object but just returned `None`, probably because of an i/o-error or an invalid argument.

Whatever function you use to get the request, I suggest checking, whether it works and what exactly it returns.